# Retrieve DateTime doesn't Load EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have the following model.

```
public class Customer
{
     [Key]
     public int CustomerId { get; set; }
     public string CustomerName { get; set; }
     public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
}
```

From the model, I generate scaffold controller. Then I have the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
     if (id == null)
     {
          return NotFound();
     }
     var obj = await _db.Customers.FindAsync(id);
     if (obj == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }
     return View(obj);
}
```

It will triggered when user clicked the `edit` link on the table. But, the `RegisteredDate` didn't retrieved to the view. I have the following view:

```
<input asp-for="CustomerId" hidden />
<input asp-for="CustomerName" />
<input asp-for="RegisteredDate" />
```

Why the `RegisteredDate` didn't load to the view? But If I add `type="datetime"`, the data is loaded. The problem is, `DateTime` picker dropdown is not appears.

[image: Without type='datetime']

[image: With type="datetime", notice that there's no icon for datetime picker]

1st pic is without `type="datetime"` and 2nd pic is with `type="datetime"` (notice there's no datetime picker icon on it).

please advice.
thank you.

Comment: Use your browser's Developer Tools to inspect the `input` element and see what's going on. Does the third `input` have `type=datetime`? Does it have some other class or style that changes how it works? Have you used a jQuery DateTimePicker perhaps? What is the *actual* generated HTML?  `type="datetime"` is part of HTML, not controlled by ASP.NET Core or EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your customer class add Datatype to RegisteredDate like this

```
public class Customer
{
 [Key]
 public int CustomerId { get; set; }
 public string CustomerName { get; set; }
 
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.